# Doubled Logs in LogCat on app start

Tags: android, logcat

When I start my app and each constructor is called I get doubled logs in LogCat form Logs in that constructors. After that everything is OK. Should I be worried?

For example, if i put in onCreate this line:

```
Log.i("a", "42");
```

When I run app, I get something like that in LogCat:

```
07-19 18:56:41.086: I/a(3343): 42
07-19 18:56:41.505: I/a(3343): 42
```

If I put any Log.i(...) in onTouchEvent there is only one log for each touchEvent.

[EDIT]
I put line that insert one record to database. Every time I run my app two record are being added, so LogCat works good and Android itself is broken.
My android: 2.3.5, HTC Sense 3.5, mod: Android Revolution HD 7.0.4 by mike1986
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting adb. 
"adb kill-server" then "adb usb" if that is what you are using.
I have seen weird issues with adb before.